# Can IDEA be configured to build a jar and run the tests from that?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm finding that running tests where the classes are on the filesystem is extremely slow due to security manager checks having to search every single element of the file path for symbolic links.

In production this sort of performance problem doesn't exist because all the classes and resources are in jar files.

Is there some way to get IDEA itself to package the classes and resources (and test classes and test resources) into a jar so that the tests can run from that? We use Gradle, so a solution involving that may also be a valid option.

Comment: Configure your antivirus/firewall to exclude directories with the project files, the IDE installation home and IDE [settings/caches directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) from the scan.

Comment: I don't have a virus scanner at the moment but disabling Spotlight on the project directories is one of the tricks we employ to hose the system less when checking projects out.

Answer (score -1):

Running `gradle build` from the terminal should be automatically configured to run your unit tests. Build times with gradle are pretty quick in my experience, and it should only recompile classes whose source files have changed, so running `gradle build` successively should take less time.

Comment: It does, but seemingly not from a jar.

Comment: Is it at least faster than running from IntelliJ? Running your tests in less time is more important than running from a jar, yes?

Comment: Running tests in IntelliJ has always been slow for me, so I almost always run the full suite from the command line using either Maven or Gradle (depends on project, though I strongly prefer gradle)

Comment: It's just as slow. IntelliJ builds the tests slightly faster because it's doing a better job of knowing which classes need to be recompiled, but in the case of running the tests, the bulk of the slowness is calls to File.getCanonicalFile for security manager checks.

Comment: Yep. Doing real File I/O in unit tests leads to slow unit tests. In this case, I would restructure your tests/code to make less real calls to File.getCanonicalFile in your unit tests.

Comment: Hence submitting this question about how to reduce the file I/O calls by loading classes from a single jar instead of many files. Do you understand now? :)

Comment: Why do your unit tests need to do real File I/O? What are they testing? Do all of our unit tests that read in files need to?

Comment: To be clear: you can write a custom JUnit runner and configure IntelliJ to do what you want to do. However, I do not think that will actually fix your problem of slow unit tests, but merely put a configuration band-aid on the real problem: File I/O is slow, and you are doing File I/O in your unit tests. Therefore, your unit tests are slow.

Comment: To run the tests, classes have to be loaded. If the classes are stored in individual files, every class you load is more file I/O which the security manager then has to check. If the classes are stored in a single jar file, then you only have to check it once when you open it. Whether the tests themselves touch files is irrelevant to the discussion - the issue occurs even for tests which do not touch files themselves.

Comment: I misunderstood. So the problem is that loading an individual class takes a long time due to your filesystem's security manager. Does that security manager need to run during your unit tests?

Comment: Loading one class doesn't take a noticeably long time in itself, but loading enough classes to run the test takes most of the time running the test. The security manager does need to run - it's present mostly to prevent badly-behaving third party code from writing to places it isn't supposed to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166280/discussion-between-binskits-and-trejkaz).